# Inno Setup. Как сделать так, чтобы при установке поверх не перетирался конкретный файл?

Tags: inno-setup

Имеется такая проблема со скриптом Inno Setup.
В программе имеется файл conf.ini. Как сделать так, чтобы при установке программы поверх уже существующей этот файл не перетирался? Может файлу можно прописать какой-то флаг или что-то в этом роде?
Спасибо!

Comment: Ну то есть, чтобы была какая-то проверка: если файла нет - ставим, если уже есть - не перетираем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно использовать флаг `onlyifdoesntexist`, он как раз проверяет, есть ли файл в системе пользователя.

```
Source: "C:\YourDirHere\conf.ini"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: onlyifdoesntexist
```

[Inno Setup docs](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=onlyifdoesntexist)